# Select Text Between Two Words and Delete Empty Lines

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I am trying to delete empty lines occurring in a word document between two placeholders.

1. I am not sure how to find the position of the placeholders within the entire document.
2. I am not sure how to search between the placeholders and replace multiple carriage returns with a single carriage return.

I tried to convert the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425595/word-vba-how-to-select-text-between-two-substrings-and-assign-to-variable) but couldn't get it working.

Comment: please post YOUR code that you currently have so we can work from that.

Answer (score 0):

If your placeholders are always the same, you can accomplish the whole thing from Word's Find and Replace dialog. No code necessary.

For example, to replace multiple carriage returns:

- Ctrl+H
- turn "Use Wildcards" on
- Find: (Placeholder1)^13{2,}(Placeholder2)  \include the parentheses
- Replace: \1 ^13 \2

If you're trying to incorporate this into a bigger block of code:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "(Placeholder1)^13{2,}(Placeholder2)"
    .Replacement.Text="\1" & " ^13 " & "\2"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
End With
```

Let me know if that works for you.