# Extract text between two words within a Larger Query

Tags: excel, pdf, ms-word, vba

Thank you for taking the time to read my request. I have tried using a few answers on this site and I am not getting what I want. (I tried this: [Word VBA how to select text between two substrings and assign to variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425595/word-vba-how-to-select-text-between-two-substrings-and-assign-to-variable))

I am trying to select a number that is ALWAYS between the two same words. It is between "Account No.:" and "IMPORTANT" (yes in all caps, unsure if caps/ no-caps matters for denoting it).

I am creating a macro where I open a word document with say 200 pages. I want to open and save EACH PAGE as it's own pdf with a specific name. I have gotten the code to run where I open and save as PDF. What I want to do, is with in that code, have something that finds the text between "Account No.:" and "IMPORTANT", selects it and copies it. This text is an account number.

Then, when I go to save the file, I want it to paste the account number as the file name. Or have a reference that when it finds the account number it assigns it to a variable. I am new to VBA, so if you can please be descriptive, and put instructions in laymans terms. THANK YOU!

My macro:

```
Sub CutePDFWriter()

Dim FName, FPath, username, LoanNo As String
Dim wordapp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngParagraphs As Range

'open doc and export as a pdf
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open("G:\test.doc")

For i = 1 To wordDoc.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")

**Here is where I want to add the “Find and Select” code**

'set variable strings
FPath = "G:\Excel Doc Tests\"
FName = "___**Here is where I want the acct nbr to go_______"** & i & ""

wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FPath & FName & "-escrtax", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=i, To:=i

Next i

'empty word doc objects
wordDoc.Close (False)
wordapp.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment to the question at that link which makes his code work. But I spent time on this: (tested with "blah blah Account No.:123-456IMPORTANT blah blah"):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sub1()
  Dim i&, FName$ ' I presume
  Dim i1&, i2&, s1$, rngDoc As Range
  Selection.HomeKey wdStory ' ?
  i1 = getPoint("Account No.:", 1) ' get start
  i2 = getPoint("IMPORTANT", 2) ' get end
  Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Range(i1, i2)
  s1 = rngDoc.Text
  FName = "Prefix" & s1 & "Postfix" & Str$(i)
  Stop ' and hover over FName
End Sub

Function getPoint&(sText$, iStart&) ' 1 for start, 2 for end
  With Selection.Find
    .Text = sText
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
  End With
  If iStart = 1 Then
    getPoint = Selection.End
  Else
    getPoint = Selection.Start
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I use this in reference to my original query? Im sorry, I am new at this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I got it situated in my query, but I am having trouble getting it to loop and select the current page in the word doc. It is looping on "i" over all, but after the: For i = 1 To wordDoc.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Number of Pages"), I situated the Sub/End Sub, and some how need to reference what the "Selection" is so when it gets down to the Function it knows what the "Selection" is. I've tried "Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=i", bookmarks "\page" etc.... no luck. Suggestions? Thanks!