# select text between strings repeatly inside a Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've built the following code (slightly adapted from a stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426863))

```
Sub findTest()
    Dim firstTerm As String
    Dim secondTerm As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim documentText As String
    Dim startPos As Long 'Stores the starting position of firstTerm
    Dim stopPos As Long 'Stores the starting position of secondTerm based on first term's location
    Dim nextPosition As Long 'The next position to search for the firstTerm

    nextPosition = 1

    'First and Second terms as defined by your example.  Obviously, this will have to be more dynamic
    'if you want to parse more than justpatientFirstname.
    firstTerm = "<tag>"
    secondTerm = "</tag>"

    'Get all the document text and store it in a variable.
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    'Maximum limit of a string is 2 billion characters.
    'So, hopefully your document is not bigger than that.  However, expect declining performance based on how big doucment is
    documentText = myRange '.Text

    'Loop documentText till you can't find any more matching "terms"
    Do Until nextPosition = 0
        startPos = InStr(nextPosition, documentText, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)
        stopPos = InStr(startPos, documentText, secondTerm, vbTextCompare)
        ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=startPos + Len(firstTerm), End:=stopPos - 1).Select ' = True
        Debug.Print Selection.Text
        nextPosition = InStr(stopPos, documentText, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)
    Loop
End Sub
```

to search and replace (I've not implemented the replace operation yet) the text between `<tag>` and `</tag>` text inside the cells of a table.
It happens that each selection shifts some characters on the right.
For example, if I have:

```
| <tag>Bill</tag> | <tag>Steve</tag> | <tag>Mark</tag> |
```

I get on the console:

```
ill
eve<
k</t
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Tables have "end of cell" and "end of row"characters (for example) which might not make it into the extracted `Text` property you're searching.  If you have tables then it's best to use Word's built-in search function to find your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Instr is not reliable where tables and/or fields are involved. For your purposes, use a Word wildcard Find, along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrOut As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\<tag\>*\</tag\>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      StrOut = StrOut & vbCr & Split(Split(.Text, ">")(1), "<")(0)
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Found:" & StrOut
End Sub
```