# search a text inside a table in a Word document and replace it with an image

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to replace each occurrence of `<tag>filename123</tag>` inside a table in a Word document with the image `D:\images\filename123.jpg` (every tag content is different).
I use the following code, copied from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56139762/268721), which does well the search command but I'm unable to make the replace line working. What's wrong?

```
Sub Demo()
Dim StrOut As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\<tag\>*\</tag\>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      StrOut = Split(Split(.Text, ">")(1), "<")(0)
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    ' the following line yields "Run-time error 9"
    .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
    "D:\images\" & StrOut, LinkToFile:=False _
    , SaveWithDocument:=True
    .Text = ""
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Lookig at your code,

- I see that this tag will always be present inside of a table. **".Information(wdWithInTable)"**
- I also changed **'split'** to **'replace'** to avoid playing with indexes.
- You were **missing** the **file extension** in your image code so **replace** **'.png'** with whatever format of image you have

```
Sub Demo()
Dim StrOut As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\<tag\>*\</tag\>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      StrOut = Replace(Replace(.Text, "<tag>", ""), "</tag>", "")
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    ' the following line yields "Run-time error 9"
    .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
    "C:\Users\xyz\" & StrOut + ".png", LinkToFile:=False _
    , SaveWithDocument:=True
    .Text = ""
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```